# why do I get two consecutive viewcontrollers when carrying out segue to show details

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, segue

when I click on the uicollectionViewCell then I come to a ViewController that is empty and a split second later a new ViewController is createdvshowing the data correctly. Going back I have to click the back button twice to navigate back to the original viewController. In the MainStoryboard I have a "show detail" segue implemented. What is going on here? What do I have to check?? Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    key = cell.keyImage.image

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showKeyDetails", sender:self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showKeyDetails"{
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? KeyDetailViewController{
            if key != nil{
                destVC.key = key
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably wired your segue from the collectionView cell.  So, when you select the cell, a segue is fired, and then `performSegue` creates a second segue.  If you want to call `performSegue`, then wire the segue from the viewController icon at the top of the viewController.

Comment: so , do I have to wire the segue from the viewController?

Comment: You can either 1) get rid of the `performSegue` call or 2) wire the segue from the viewController icon at the top of the VC instead of from the cell.

Comment: great , tried 2) and it works, thanks!! However, tried 1) and double viewController disappears OK, but the data did not come through ("key" in above code ). I wonder why?

Comment: sorry, but that did not work

Comment: This is a correct version of a previous comment... The data doesn't come through because the segue happens before `didSelectItem` runs. In that case, the cell is passed as the sender so you should do `destVC.key = (sender as! CollectionViewCell).keyImage.image`.  My answer below shows how to do that safely (without the crash operator `!`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wired your segue from the collectionView cell. So, when you select the cell, a segue fires, and then `performSegue` creates a second segue.

To fix this, you can either:

1. Remove the `performSegue` call, remove the `didSelectItem` function and update your `prepare(for:sender:)` function to find the key:

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "showKeyDetails"{
           if let destVC = segue.destination as? KeyDetailViewController,
              let cell = sender as? CollectionViewCell,
              let key = cell.keyImage.image
           {
               destVC.key = key
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   **OR:**

   2) Wire the segue from the viewController icon at the top of the VC instead of from the cell.